# Load multiple entities eagerly with .Include()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to load eagerly a class A instance with a certain Id. Then I want to .Include every class B instance related to A instance and .Include every C instance related to B instance.

This does not work:

```
var schoolyear = _context.Schoolyears
                .Include(s => s.SchoolclassCodes)
                .Include(s => s.TimeTableEntries)
                .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == schoolyearId);
```

The last .Include is on the wrong level. It must relate to the .SchoolclassCodes.

Is this not possible with the stronly typed .Include() or do I have to use the weaked type style:

```
var schoolyear = _context.Schoolyears
                       .Include("SchoolclassCode.TimeTableEntries")
                       .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == schoolyearId);


class Schoolyear
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public ICollection<SchoolclassCode> {get;set;}
}

class SchoolclassCode
{
   public ICollection<TimeTableEntry> {get;set;}

}

class TimeTableEntry
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the stongly typed method as well.

Just make a select query in the `Include` until you reach the last entity in the hierarchy that should be loaded:

```
var schoolyear = _context.Schoolyears
                     .Include(s => s.SchoolclassCodes
                         .Select(t => t.TimeTableEntries));
```

Comment: Yes it even worked with my needed SingleOrDefault, thanks. Seems I have overlooked the .Select() on that site its just there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx